# parsing first and last name from fullname column

Tags: sql, parsing

Below is the data I am trying to manipulate. I am trying to get the last name and first name before the second comma

[image]

This is the code I currently have:

```
SELECT     
[SDN_Name],         
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(', ', [SDN_Name]) > 0 THEN
    LEFT([SDN_Name],(CHARINDEX(', ',[SDN_Name],1)-1))    
ELSE         
     [SDN_Name]    
END as LName,
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(', ', [SDN_Name]) > 0 THEN  
   SUBSTRING([SDN_Name],CHARINDEX(', ',[SDN_Name])+1, ( LEN([SDN_Name]) - CHARINDEX(', ',[SDN_Name])+1))
ELSE         
    NULL     
END as FName
```

FROM [Staging].[OFAC].[TP1] 
Where ([SDN_Type] = 'individual')

For instance, if the full name is DELOS REYES, Feliciano , Jr.
I want DELOS REYES as the LName
and Feliciano Semborio as the Fname
but I don't want to capture ", Jr."

I'm able to parse the last name and everything right of the first comma. 
How do I write a CASEstatment that will capture the first name without the suffix of the name?

Comment: Please could you show what results you *want* as well as the results that you are getting.  *(What about your current solution in particular is not giving the behaviour up you desire?)*

Comment: the last picture is the result set i am getting. 
the reselt set i want is..for example:
SDN_Name 
ABDELNUR, Nury de Jesus
 
LName
ABDELNUR

FName
Nury

I can't get LName to give me just the first name, I don't want anything after the space in the Fname column

Answer (score 0):

Those are commas in SDN_Name field, right?  Just use the *CharIndex* of ', ' instead of ' ', and it should work.  Like this:

```
SELECT [SDN_Name],         
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(', ', [SDN_Name]) > 0 THEN
        LEFT([SDN_Name],CHARINDEX(', ',[SDN_Name])-1)     
    ELSE         
        [SDN_Name]    
    END as LName,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(', ', [SDN_Name]) > 0 THEN        
        SUBSTRING([SDN_Name], CHARINDEX(', ',[SDN_Name])+2, 
            CASE WHEN RIGHT([SDN_Name], 1) = '.' THEN LEN([SDN_Name]-2) ELSE LEN([SDN_Name]) END
            - (2+CHARINDEX(', ',[SDN_NAME],1))
        )
    ELSE         
        NULL     
    END as FName
```

Comment: yes, they are commas but the middle initial on some fields are still showing up in the result set. your solution shaved off 2 spaces of the original reult set

Comment: @user1169520 Thanks, fixed the error that was cutting off characters.  I don't see middle initials in the records you showed ... are there more records with SDN_Names like **LASTNAME, First M.** or something like that?

Comment: @user1169520 Ok, I took another crack at it.  Assuming the last initial is one character long and ends with a period.

Comment: opps sorry, didnt finish my sentenc. For example: the first row...says "Nury de Jess" I want it to output as "Nury", same as the 3rd and 5th row. am i making sense?

Comment: @user1169520  Ah, so only the first "word" of the first name?  Ok, I think I've got it now.

Comment: That didn't work either...it actually added two more characters to the result set

Comment: I am actually looking for the name to the right of the first comma before the second coma. Sorry for the confusion, I read the requirements wrong.